# Axios returning empty on get call for nested data

Tags: javascript, json, axios

I am trying to get a 2d array using axios but when i console.log it it returns empty :/

My code:

```js
let orig = []
      axios
        .get(<endpoint url here>)
        .then(response => {
          orig = response.data.activity_history
        })

      console.log('Orig -> ' + JSON.stringify(orig))
```

My endpoint is built to return data like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    ...
    "activity_history": [
        [
            "Test",
            "Test",
            "Test",
            "Test",
            "Test"
        ]
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get the 2d array so I could push another array in it in the frontend, but when i console.log `orig` it returns `Orig -> []`. Any help?

Comment: A possible solution would be to add `await axios.get()`

Comment: This question gets asked many times a day, voting to close as duplicate

Comment: Yeah it was with the whole thing being async, i marked this as a duplicate since it's been answered already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the `console.log` doesnt wait for the axios call to finish. One option would be to add `await` to your axios. Other option would be to do all actions with your Orig in the `then` function like:

```
  axios
        .get(<endpoint url here>)
        .then(response => {
          orig = response.data.activity_history;
          console.log('Orig -> ' + JSON.stringify(orig))
        })
```